# Scraping tables from link in R

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

Hi i want to scrape tabular information from the following page on Asset Allocation, Style Details, Sector Weightings & World Regions

http://portfolios.morningstar.com/fund/summary?t=SPY&region=usa&culture=en-US&ownerCountry=USA

I have the following code which gives an error

```
turl = 'http://portfolios.morningstar.com/fund/summary?t=SPY'
test_html = read_html(turl) 
df<-html_table(test_html, fill = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within the examples of `?html_table` is the following example:

```
births <- read_html("https://www.ssa.gov/oact/babynames/numberUSbirths.html")
html_table(html_nodes(births, "table")[[2]])
```

Adapting this to your case seems to remove the error.  You may need to change the`[[2]]]` depending on exactly what you want.

```
library(rvest)
turl = 'http://portfolios.morningstar.com/fund/summary?t=SPY'
test_html = read_html(turl) 
df<-html_table(html_nodes(test_html, 'table')[[2]])
```

Comment: Thanks, Very helpful. I am still getting the same error for one of the tables but for the rest of them I am able to scrape using this